# OSX - Unable to copy files from local file system to hdfs

Tags: macos, hadoop

I'm trying to copy files from a local file system to the HDFS and it throws up an error indicating the file could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of 1.

```
ckharide-mac:bin hadoop$ ./hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /tmp/wcinput /user/hadoop/app/input
13/10/01 13:25:05 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /user/hadoop/app/input/LICENSE.txt could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1920)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:783)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)
```

I was able to create the directory though but copying of files doesn't work. I have tried reformatting the name node and stopped/starting the hadoop services still the problem persists.

Any help please is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that your DataNodes are up and running fine. And if they are running, they are able to talk to the NameNode.

Also, make sure you have enough space to store the file in your HDFS.

Answer (score 1):

some things you can do:

- reformat: `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop namenode -format`
- Check System Preferences->Sharing->Remote Login activated?
- restart hadoop `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/stop-all.sh` and then `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/start-all.sh`

I ran into the same issue the other day on my Mac and above steps at least helped me out...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks that fixed it there wasnt any space on the HDFS and that gets recognized only when we move files from teh local file system to the HDFS one . Once i addressed that i did a format and followed the start of the hadopp services and it worked.